# How to show a own search query result on a page on wordpress

Tags: database, wordpress, function

I'm working on wordpress now. I have database with some tables, teacher, lesson and list lesson. The list lesson is a junction table between teacher and lesson. I want to make a page where the user can search a teacher. User can search teacher based on the lesson teacher teach. In example, the user select Math for Junior High School, so after press the submit button, the web will show the result.

I've tried to create own page manually, not from wordpress. I called the get_header() function  and so on and than put my php.code below but it doesnt work. Now, I'm trying to make a function, but I have no idea how to send the paramater for query and how to show the result.

Any helps is appreciated. Thank you! :)

Comment: 'I have database with some tables, teacher, lesson and list lesson' are this table custom which u created or you storing teacher,lesson details in one of the wp tables?

Comment: I create this custom table on same database on wordpress. So instead of wp_post and others table, I also created table teacher and other custom table

Comment: you have to write custom query.. this can help you. http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/writing-custom-queries-in-wordpress/